# How to pass model object to the controller function using Http.GetFromJsonAsync in Blazor

Tags: json, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to pass a complete model object to a controller function using `Http.GetFromJsonAsync`

My model Search filter gets the values from front end:

```
    public Models.SearchFilter SearchFilter { get; set; } = new Models.SearchFilter();
  private List<Models.UtpResult> lst_Company;
```

I have used the below code but its not working. Error message is cant convert model type to System.text.JsonJsonserializer:

```
lst_Company = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Models.Result >>("api/Services/SearchCompany", SearchFilter );
```

Controller function is :

```
  [HttpGet("company/search")]
        public Models.Result SearchCompany([FromBody] Models.SearchFilter filter)
        {
            return _iTRepository.SearchCompany(filter);
        }
```

Comment: `List<Models.Result>` != `Models.Result`. Basically what the first answer is saying.

Comment: Sorry i ddint get you. But i updated the question. Is this what you meant?

Comment: The answer from @Alamakanambra should be all you need. If not, post more detials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic method on an API service that I use to retrieve paged lists.  It demonstrates using `PostAsJsonAsync` and how to retrieve the result.  You can pass the SearchFilter in the same way.

```
public override async ValueTask<List<TRecord>> SelectPagedRecordsAsync<TRecord>(RecordPagingData pagingData)
{
  var response = await this.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"/api/{GetRecordName<TRecord>()}/listpaged", pagingData);
  return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<TRecord>>();
}
```

and the Server Controller to handle it:

```
[MVC.Route("/api/weatherforecast/listpaged")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<List<WeatherForecast>> Read([FromBody] RecordPagingData data) => await DataService.SelectPagedRecordsAsync<WeatherForecast>(data);
```

##### Addition

Your call would look something like this:

```
var response = await this.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/Services/SearchCompany", SearchFilter );
lst_Company = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Models.UtpResult>>();
```

and controller

```
[HttpPost("company/search")]
public async Task<List<Models.UtpResult>> SearchCompany([FromBody] Models.SearchFilter filter) 
{
// I assume this is async?
return await _iTRepository.SearchCompany(filter);

// else miss out the async and

return Task.FromResult(_iTRepository.SearchCompany(filter));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But its POST method. Will this return search result too?

Comment: `PostAsJsonAsync` lets you pass an object and returns a `HttpResponseMethod` which you then unbundle with `response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<TRecord>>()` to get the List<TRecord>.  See my addition to the answer.

Comment: Very well answered  Thanks let me try this out.. I have given your answer +1 .

Answer (score 1):

Expected return type `List<Models.SearchFilter>` does not match the return type of the controller: `Models.Result`.

Also, the second parameter in GetFromJsonAsync is wrong. You cannot pass model like that using `GET`. You have to convert it to be part of url, or use `POST` for that.